# Removing firefox make me install kde library (I am using unity)

Tags: firefox, kde

I was trying to remove firefox, but this makes me install kde library...
I am currently using ubuntu unity 17.04.
How to solve it?

```
user: ~$  sudo apt-get remove firefox

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  breeze-icon-theme icoutils kate-data katepart kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-runtime kde-runtime-data
  kde-style-breeze kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kwayland-data
  kwayland-integration libattica0.4 libclucene-core1v5 libdlrestrictions1 libfam0 libgpgme++2v5 libkactivities6
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5
  libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkf5archive5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5config-bin
  libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5coreaddons-data
  libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5 libkf5style5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data
  libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4
  libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4
  libkxmlrpcclient4 libnl-route-3-200 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpolkit-qt5-1-1
  libqca2 libqca2-plugins libqoauth1 libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt5script5 libqtwebkit4 libsolid4 libstreamanalyzer0v5
  libstreams0v5 libthreadweaver4 ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common plasma-scriptengine-javascript rekonq

Suggested packages:
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl djvulibre-bin finger fam hspell phonon-backend-mplayer
  phonon-backend-vlc phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer kget


The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox


The following NEW packages will be installed:

  breeze-icon-theme icoutils kate-data katepart kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-runtime kde-runtime-data
  kde-style-breeze kde-style-breeze-qt4 kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools kwayland-data
  kwayland-integration libattica0.4 libclucene-core1v5 libdlrestrictions1 libfam0 libgpgme++2v5 libkactivities6
  libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5
  libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkf5archive5 libkf5auth-data libkf5auth5 libkf5codecs-data libkf5codecs5 libkf5config-bin
  libkf5config-data libkf5configcore5 libkf5configgui5 libkf5configwidgets-data libkf5configwidgets5 libkf5coreaddons-data
  libkf5coreaddons5 libkf5guiaddons5 libkf5i18n-data libkf5i18n5 libkf5iconthemes-bin libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5
  libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews-data libkf5itemviews5 libkf5style5 libkf5waylandclient5 libkf5widgetsaddons-data
  libkf5widgetsaddons5 libkf5windowsystem-data libkf5windowsystem5 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4
  libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkparts4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4
  libkxmlrpcclient4 libnl-route-3-200 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libphonon4 libplasma3 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpolkit-qt5-1-1
  libqca2 libqca2-plugins libqoauth1 libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt5script5 libqtwebkit4 libsolid4 libstreamanalyzer0v5
  libstreams0v5 libthreadweaver4 ntrack-module-libnl-0 oxygen-icon-theme phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer
  phonon-backend-gstreamer-common plasma-scriptengine-javascript rekonq
0 upgraded, 99 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 142 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `firefox` package provides `www-browser`. When you remove `firefox` when there are no any other packages in your system that provides `www-browser`, apt will automatically select another package that provides `www-browser` to install. In your case, it selected `rekonq`, the KDE browser.

If you don't want to install KDE, you should install another browser first, say Chrome, before removing Firefox.